# can I use a wildcard in a datasheet view custom filter to NOT show titles that begin with certain words?

Tags: datasheet

I have a calendar list view and want to be able to filter on the title to NOT show items that begin with the word Deleted.

Can you use a wildcard at the end of Deleted to grab all titles that begin with deleted?

Example
Does Not equal    Deleted*

Thanks,
Rhonda

Answer (score 0):

You might try a calculated column to provide an additional filtering capability. There's a good example in a thread about a [CAML Query for not begins with](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/caml-query-to-find-a-value-that-does-not-begin-with).

> =IF(LEFT([Title], 7)="myvalue", "YES", "NO")

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark as answer so others will know more easily than reading the comments